# ¿Streamlit y firebase-ui-auth funcionan juntos?

Tags: python, firebase

He intentado obtener el botón de Google de firebase-ui-auth desde firebase con Streamlit:

Tengo el siguiente código en Streamlit:

```
import streamlit as st
from streamlit.components.v1 import html

def main():
    st.title("Mostrar HTML en Streamlit")


    return html("""
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Automatizados</title>
        <script src="static/css/style.css"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/3.5.2/firebaseui.css" />
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.3.0/firebase-ui-auth.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='firebaseui-auth-container'></div>

        <script>
        const firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "XXXXXXXX",
            authDomain: "XXXXXXXX",
            projectId: "XXXXXXXX",
            storageBucket: "XXXXXXXX",
            messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXX",
            appId: "XXXXXXXX",
            measurementId: "XXXXXXXX",
            clientId:"XXXXXXXX"
        };

        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

        // FirebaseUI config.
        var uiConfig = {
            signInSuccessUrl: 'http://localhost:8501/',
            signInOptions: [
                firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
            ],
            // Terms of service url.
            tosUrl: '',
            callbacks: {
                signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function(authResult, redirectUrl){
                    // User successfully signed in.
                    window.location =  'http://localhost:8501/';
                    return false;
                }
            }
        };

            const ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth())

            const uiContainer = document.getElementById('firebaseui-auth-container');
            ui.start(uiContainer, uiConfig);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
""")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Con los siguientes problemas:

Cuando le doy click al botón de Google, me aparece el siguiente error: This operation is not supported in the environment this application is running on. "location.protocol" must be http, https or chrome-extension and web storage must be enabled.

Y en la consola obtengo: [ 0.980s] [firebaseui] signInWithRedirect: auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment